# hide each element by id when container appended

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have dynamically appended elements:

```
var card =
              `<hr>
            <h3>
          <p class="text-center id="i" >${title}</p>
          </h3>
          <video class="col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" id="mp4Id" controls="controls">
          <source src=${mp4} type="video/mp4">?????????
          </video>
            <img class="col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" id= "imgId" src=${images}>
            <div class="span4 collapse-group">
              <div class="text-center">
                <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#">Check &raquo;</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse">
                <div class="card card-body">
                ${text}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`

            $('.container').append(card);
```

This func works for my buttons :

```
$(document).find(".card").each(function() {
          $(this)
            .closest('.collapse-group')
            .find('.btn')
            .toggle($(this).text().length > 34);
        });
```

But when I want to call my `video class` for id `id="mp4Id"` it doesnt work:

```
$(document).find("#mp4Id").each(function() {
          $(this)
            .hide()
        });
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`. Change the `mp4` elements to use a class instead. Also the `imgId` elements too, although they're not relevant the current problem

Answer (score 0):

Since id is unique and should not be repeated. So using `.find()` does not make sense.
If your id of element is unique, then you can achieved by using below code-:

```
$('#mp4Id').hide();
```

*or*

```
$('#mp4Id').addClass('hidden');
```